# How should i correctly re-write an existing update trigger to handle multiple updated values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following trigger code that works well on single row updates, but fails for multiple row updates. I'd like to fix this and have been looking around at solutions.

I did consider using cursors as an easy option to fix the problem, but i'm aware that they are a bad idea in triggers.

I want to rewrite this the 'right' way, but i'm not an expert in this area and would appreciate some help and advice to get it rewritten correctly.

Can anyone help?

This is the code for the current trigger:

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Entity_Class_ID as int,
    @Entity_Identifier as varchar(50),
    @Postcode as varchar(100),
    @Latitude as numeric(18,9),
    @Longitude as numeric(18,9)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED) -- Check if an Update and use postcode from inserted 
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT Postal_Code from INSERTED) != (SELECT Postal_Code from DELETED)
        BEGIN
            SET @Entity_Class_ID = (SELECT top 1 Entity_Class_ID from INSERTED order by Mailing_Address_ID desc)
            SET @Entity_Identifier = (SELECT top 1 Entity_Identifier from INSERTED order by Entity_Identifier desc)

            IF @Entity_Class_ID = 3 BEGIN
                SET @Postcode = (SELECT top 1 Postal_Code from INSERTED order by Mailing_Address_ID desc)

                    IF @Postcode is not null BEGIN

                    DECLARE @URL varchar(MAX)

                    SET @URL = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/' +
                    @Postcode +
                    '?o=xml&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

                    DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
                    DECLARE @XML xml
                    DECLARE @obj int
                    DECLARE @Result int
                    DECLARE @HTTPStatus int
                    DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

                    EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Obj OUT

                    BEGIN TRY
                        EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
                        EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, ''
                        EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT
                        EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml', @Response OUT
                    END TRY
                    BEGIN CATCH
                        SET @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
                    END CATCH

                    EXEC @Result = sp_OADestroy @Obj

                    IF (@ErrorMsg IS NOT NULL) OR (@HTTPStatus <> 200)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @ErrorMsg = 'Error in spGeocode: ' + ISNULL(@ErrorMsg, 'HTTP result is: ' + CAST(@HTTPStatus AS varchar(10)))
                        RAISERROR(@ErrorMsg, 16, 1, @HTTPStatus)
                        RETURN
                    END

                    SET @XML = CAST(@Response AS XML)

                    SET @Latitude = @XML.value('
                    declare namespace BM="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";
                    (/BM:Response/BM:ResourceSets/BM:ResourceSet/BM:Resources/BM:Location/BM:Point/BM:Latitude)[1]', 'numeric(18,9)')
                    SET @Longitude = @XML.value('
                    declare namespace BM="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";
                    (/BM:Response/BM:ResourceSets/BM:ResourceSet/BM:Resources/BM:Location/BM:Point/BM:Longitude)[1]', 'numeric(18,9)')
                    END


                    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EXT_BI_Additional_Fields WHERE Project_ID = @Entity_Identifier)
                    UPDATE EXT_BI_Additional_Fields SET Latitude = @Latitude, Longitude = @Longitude 
                    WHERE Project_ID = @Entity_Identifier
                    ELSE
                    INSERT INTO EXT_BI_Additional_Fields (Project_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Project_Number, Project_Code)
                    select TOP (1) Project_ID, @Latitude, @Longitude, null as Project_Number, Project_Code
                    from  dbo.Project
                    WHERE Project_ID = @Entity_Identifier
                    order by Project_ID DESC


            END
        END
    END
END
```

This is the table that the trigger sits on (Mailing_Address):

[image]

This is the table that gets updated with the results of the trigger (EXT_BI_Additional_Fields):

```
Project_ID  Latitude    Longitude   Project_Number  Project_Code
44          51.540180   -0.302364   12255           NULL
46          51.585091   -0.337701   12247           NULL
```

The way this trigger currently works is that when a Postal_Code is updated in the 'mailing_address' table, it sends the updated Postal_Code value to the Bing Maps REST service for geocoding. The returned latitude and longitude values are then either inserted or updated into the 'EXT_BI_Additional_Fields' table.

For ease of maintenance / human readability, the above insert also pulls in Project_Number and Project_Code values from the table 'Project'

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Why are you using a trigger in the first place? Especially if the logic is this complex?

Comment: @JanineRawnsley - Because i have access to the database level, but not the front end and to be honest it works well for my use case... except on rare occasions when i need to update a lot of postcodes in one go. :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've provided more detail as requested.